# Retornar un dato al consumir una API usando https.get | NODE JS

Tags: nodejs, api

Estoy tratando de obtener los datos de la API de pokemon usando solamente https.get, de node js, luego queria retornar los datos que obtengo, en este caso el nombre o guardarlo en una variable llamada namePokemon, pero de la manera que lo hago no retorna nada. Si imprimo el name dentro del then, me trae el nombre del pokemon, pero si le asigno este dato a la variable que esta por fuera, esta al querer imprimirla despues es undefined.

```
const https = require('https');
function getData() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    https.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/ditto', (resp, err) => {
      if (err) reject(err);
      let data = '';
      resp.on('data', (chunk) => (data += chunk));
      resp.on('end', () => {
        resolve(JSON.parse(data).forms[0].name);
      });
    });
  });
}
let namePokemon;
getData()
  .then((name) => {
    namePokemon = name;
    console.log(name);
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log('Un error salvaje aparecio!', { error: err }));
console.log(namePokemon);
```

Comment: creo que es por el scope, proba de definir namePokemon como var y no como let

Comment: @Doormut Sigue quedando como undefined

Comment: para que queres guardar el nombre en una variable? en que momento la necesitas?

Comment: @Doormut Solo es una prueba que quiero hacer, ya que en un ejercicio me pidieron algo así, pero que al final dicha función retornara pues un dato, no simplemente usando un console.log

Comment: Proba dentro del then de poner: return name; y despues haces let namePokemon = getData()

Comment: @Doormut retorna una promesa.

Comment: Exacto retorna una Promesa. No puedes sacar el valor de una Promesa a un contexto superior, a menos que tu contexto sea dentro de una función tipo `async`.

Comment: Relacionado: [Hacer que una Promesa regrese algo para seguir trabajando en código asíncrono](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/364535/hacer-que-una-promesa-regrese-algo-para-seguir-trabajando-en-código-síncrono/)

Comment: @MauricioContreras Muchas gracias por tu aporte.

Answer (score 0):

Una forma usando jquery `$.get` es:

```js
function myfun() {
$.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/ditto')
.success((data)=> console.log(data.forms[0].name))
.fail(()=> console.log('Error salvaje'));
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="myfun();">Click</button>
```

Ya utiliza promesas por defecto.