# ¿Como pasar el valor de una promesa a una variable en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, get

Tengo una funcion que me retorna una [promesa](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise), al querer pasarla a una variable, devuelve `undefined`, o simplemente no retorna nada.

Necesito guardar el valor del retorno para usarlo posteriormente en mi código. También he intentado hacer la función asíncrona, sin embargo, no logro capturar el resultado.

```
function getLocalIP() {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    // NOTE: window.RTCPeerConnection is "not a constructor" in FF22/23
    var RTCPeerConnection =
      /*window.RTCPeerConnection ||*/ window.webkitRTCPeerConnection ||
      window.mozRTCPeerConnection;

    if (!RTCPeerConnection) {
      reject("Your browser does not support this API");
    }

    var rtc = new RTCPeerConnection({ iceServers: [] });
    var addrs = {};
    addrs["0.0.0.0"] = false;

    function grepSDP(sdp) {
      var hosts = [];
      var finalIP = "";
      sdp.split("\r\n").forEach(function (line) {
        // c.f. http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4566#page-39
        if (~line.indexOf("a=candidate")) {
          // http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4566#section-5.13
          var parts = line.split(" "), // http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5245#section-15.1
            addr = parts[4],
            type = parts[7];
          if (type === "host") {
            finalIP = addr;
          }
        } else if (~line.indexOf("c=")) {
          // http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4566#section-5.7
          var parts = line.split(" "),
            addr = parts[2];
          finalIP = addr;
        }
      });
      return finalIP;
    }

    if (1 || window.mozRTCPeerConnection) {
      // FF [and now Chrome!] needs a channel/stream to proceed
      rtc.createDataChannel("", { reliable: false });
    }

    rtc.onicecandidate = function (evt) {
      // convert the candidate to SDP so we can run it through our general parser
      // see https://twitter.com/lancestout/status/525796175425720320 for details
      if (evt.candidate) {
        var addr = grepSDP("a=" + evt.candidate.candidate);
        resolve(addr);
      }
    };
    rtc.createOffer(
      function (offerDesc) {
        rtc.setLocalDescription(offerDesc);
      },
      function (e) {
        console.warn("offer failed", e);
      }
    );
  });
}
```

Tengo esta funcion que intenta recuperar , sin embargo no logro obtener nada . alguna idea para poder usar el resultado de la promesa?

```
getLocalIP().then(function(getData){
  metaData = getData;
  });
```

Comment: Para resolver la promesa que retornas lo haces con ```const promise=getLocalIP(); promise.then((res)=>console.log(res))```

Comment: intenté esto :
var test = "";
const promise=getLocalIP(); 
promise.then((res)=>test = res);
Para usar posteriormente la variable test , pero no se guarda nada , y lamento las mayusculas

Comment: Verifica si la función te devuelve una promesa, imprime ```console.log(getLocalIP())``` y en consola te debería mostrar una promesa.

Comment: Por favor no dupliques preguntas, tienes [esta otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/399088/como-obtener-ip-local-con-js-y-enviar-la-variable-a-php) que trata sobre el mismo tema. Lo adecuado es editar la primera para mejorarla.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Hacer que una promesa regrese algo para seguir trabajando en código síncrono](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/364535/hacer-que-una-promesa-regrese-algo-para-seguir-trabajando-en-c%c3%b3digo-s%c3%adncrono)