# Error propiedad "length" en dependencia xlsx de nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Estoy haciendo un proyecto con *NodeJS* y *MongoDB* (utilizando Postman).
Ahora mismo estoy intentando crear un archivo excel con la dependencia xlsx, pero al ejecutar la función en Postman me muestra el siguiente error:

Código de la función:

```js
function crearExcel(req,res){
  var IdEmpresa = req.empresa.sub;
  var listaEmpleados = Empleado.find( { idEmpresa: IdEmpresa } ).exec((err, empleadosEncontrados) => {
    if(err) return res.status(500).send({ mensaje: 'Error en la petición' })
    if(!empleadosEncontrados) return res.status(500).send({ mensaje: 'Error en la consulta de Empleados' })
    if( IdEmpresa != req.empresa.sub) return res.status(500).send({ mensaje: 'No tiene los permisos necesarios para obtener los empleados de esta Empresa' })
    return empleadosEncontrados
  })
  var nuevoWB = xlsx.utils.book_new();
  var nuevoWS = xlsx.utils.json_to_sheet(listaEmpleados)
  xlsx.utils.book_append_sheet(nuevoWB,nuevoWS,"New Data")
  return res.status(200).send(xlsx.writeFile(nuevoWB,`Lista_Empleados_Empresa_${req.empresa.nombre}.xlsx`))
}
```

Error que muestra:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
> at sheet_add_json (C:\Control_De_Empresas\node_modules\xlsx\xlsx.js:21376:51)
> at Object.json_to_sheet (C:\Control_De_Empresas\node_modules\xlsx\xlsx.js:21422:43)
> at crearExcel (C:\Control_De_Empresas\src\controllers\empleado.controller.js:286:30)
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Control_De_Empresas\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
> at next (C:\Control_De_Empresas\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
> at exports.ensureAuth (C:\Control_De_Empresas\src\middlewares\authenticated.empresa.js:25:5)
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Control_De_Empresas\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
> at next (C:\Control_De_Empresas\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
> at Route.dispatch (C:\Control_De_Empresas\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Control_De_Empresas\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
> at C:\Control_De_Empresas\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
> at Function.process_params (C:\Control_De_Empresas\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
> at next (C:\Control_De_Empresas\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
> at Function.handle (C:\Control_De_Empresas\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
> at router (C:\Control_De_Empresas\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Control_De_Empresas\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Tu problema es que estás mezclando el uso de `callbacks` con asignaciones a variables como si se tratara de código sincrónico. Específicamente en esta linea:

```js
var listaEmpleados = Empleado.find( { idEmpresa: IdEmpresa } ).exec((err, empleadosEncontrados) => { ... });
```

La función [`callback`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) que estás pasando al método [`exec()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-exec) si bien se ejecuta cuando MongoDB devuelve un resultado y haces un `return` dentro de la misma, no te devolverá ese resultado inmediatamente. El detalle es que `exec()` devuelve una [Promesa](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

**SOLUCIÓN**

Para trabajar con este proceso asíncrono (toda consulta a Base de Datos MongoDB desde NodeJS (Javascript) es asíncrona), debes trabajar con la Promesa devuelta.

Tienes 2 opciones: usar [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) dentro de una [función `async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) o usar [`then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) y [`catch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) (toda Promesa implementa `then()` y `catch()`).

**Usando `async / await`**

Lo primero sería convertir tu función llamada `crearExcel` en una función *async*.  Por ejemplo:

```js
async function crearExcel(req,res) { // función tipo async
  let IdEmpresa = req.empresa.sub;
  // cuando trabajamos con Promesas y async / await, debemos usar try catch
  try {
    let listaEmpleados = await Empleado.find({ idEmpresa: IdEmpresa })
    .exec((err, empleadosEncontrados) => {
      if(err) throw error; // lanzamos el error para que lo capture catch
      if(!empleadosEncontrados.length) return; // devolvemos undefined
      return empleadosEncontrados // devolvemos los empleados encontrados
    });
    if(!listaEmpleados) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        message: `No hay empleados para ${IdEmpresa}`
      });
    }
    let nuevoWB = xlsx.utils.book_new();
    let nuevoWS = xlsx.utils.json_to_sheet(listaEmpleados)
    xlsx.utils.book_append_sheet(nuevoWB,nuevoWS,"New Data");
    return res.status(200).send(xlsx.writeFile(nuevoWB,`Lista_Empleados_Empresa_${req.empresa.nombre}.xlsx`));
  }
  catch(e) { // capturamos cualquier excepción aquí
    console.error(e.message);
    return res.status(500).json({
      message: 'Error en la consulta'
    });
  }
}
```

Como se observa en el código, puedo esperar por el resultado de la consulta a la DB (aún cuando se usa una función `callback` dentro del método `exec()`) y en base al resultado obtenido se devuelve una respuesta al cliente.

Usualmente no se mezclan funciones `callback` con Promesas por una sencilla razón: *puedes olvidar hacer el `return` o puedes olvidar que el error debe lanzarse (throw)*.

El código anterior puede escribirse de la siguiente forma **sin usar** una función `callback` dentro del método `exec()`:

```js
async function crearExcel(req,res) { // función tipo async
  let IdEmpresa = req.empresa.sub;
  // cuando trabajamos con Promesas y async / await, debemos usar try catch
  try {
    let listaEmpleados = await Empleado.find({ idEmpresa: IdEmpresa }).exec();
    if(!listaEmpleados || !listaEmpleados.length) { // listaEmpleados debe ser un Array
      return res.status(404).json({
        message: `No hay empleados para ${IdEmpresa}`
      });
    }
    let nuevoWB = xlsx.utils.book_new();
    let nuevoWS = xlsx.utils.json_to_sheet(listaEmpleados)
    xlsx.utils.book_append_sheet(nuevoWB,nuevoWS,"New Data");
    return res.status(200).send(xlsx.writeFile(nuevoWB,`Lista_Empleados_Empresa_${req.empresa.nombre}.xlsx`));
  }
  catch(e) { // capturamos cualquier excepción aquí
    console.error(e.message);
    return res.status(500).json({
      message: 'Error en la consulta'
    });
  }
}
```

**Usando `then()` y `catch()`:**

Otra forma de trabajar con Promesas es usando los métodos `then()` y `catch()` tal como hemos dicho con anterioridad. Esto significa que la lógica en caso de resultado seguirá dentro del método `then()` y la lógica en caso de error se escribe dentro del método `catch`. No es necesaria una función tipo *async* en este caso.

El código podría verse de la siguiente forma:

```js
function crearExcel(req,res) {
  let IdEmpresa = req.empresa.sub;
  Empleado
    .find({ idEmpresa: IdEmpresa }) // la consulta
    .exec() // la Promesa
    .then(listaEmpleados => { // manejo del resultado
      if(!listaEmpleados || !listaEmpleados.length) { // listaEmpleados debe ser un Array
        return res.status(404).json({
          message: `No hay empleados para ${IdEmpresa}`
        });
      }
      let nuevoWB = xlsx.utils.book_new();
      let nuevoWS = xlsx.utils.json_to_sheet(listaEmpleados)
      xlsx.utils.book_append_sheet(nuevoWB,nuevoWS,"New Data");
      return res.status(200).send(xlsx.writeFile(nuevoWB,`Lista_Empleados_Empresa_${req.empresa.nombre}.xlsx`));
    })
    .catch(e => { // manejo del posible error
      console.error(e.message);
      return res.status(500).json({
        message: 'Error en la consulta'
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Como se observa en el código, el resultado de la consulta es pasado al método `then()` y únicamente dentro de este método podrás trabajar con dicho resultado. Lo mismo ocurrirá con el posible error en la consulta, si lo hubiera.

---

En [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/364535/hacer-que-una-promesa-regrese-algo-para-seguir-trabajando-en-c%c3%b3digo-s%c3%adncrono/364745#364745) puedes conseguir más información sobre los procesos asíncronos cuando trabajamos con Promesas. En ella trato de explicar el porqué no se puede sacar el resultado de una Promesa (proceso asíncrono) fuera del método `then()` por más que usemos la sentencia `return`.