# Como extraer los datos de una Promise de axios

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs, django, react-axios

Estoy desarrollando una respuesta de tipo GET de una API, la respuesta que obtengo es la de la imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En cuanto al código de la petición es el siguiente:

```
const cardInfo = axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/Equipos/?format=json')
        .then((response) => {
            const cartas = [];
            for (let index = 0; index < 20; index++) {     
                const respuesta = response.data[index];
                var titulo = respuesta.Equipo;
                var valor = respuesta.ValorMedio;
                const cardInfo =                 
                    {
                        image: "https://cdn5.dibujos.net/dibujos/pintados/201746/escudo-del-club-atletico-de-madrid-deportes-escudos-de-futbol-11197949.jpg",
                        title:titulo,
                        text: valor
                    }
                cartas.push(cardInfo)                                        
            }
            return cartas;
        });
```

El problema lo tengo al realizar el mapeado de cada carta porque necesito solo los resultados de la promise:

```
    return(
        <section class="row mt-5 ml-5">
            <div class="col-3">
                {cardInfo.then(cardInfo => cardInfo.map(renderCard))}
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
                {cardInfo.then(cardInfo => cardInfo.map(renderCard))}
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
                {cardInfo.then(cardInfo => cardInfo.map(renderCard))}
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
                {cardInfo.then(cardInfo => cardInfo.map(renderCard))}
            </div>
        </section>
    );
```

Entiendo que al realizar la petición el proceso es asíncrono pero como se puede hacer para conseguir sacar los datos de la promise

Comment: Mi no entender... como asi que "necesito solo los datos de la respuesta para devolverlo"... podrías explicar mejor lo que quieres?

Comment: No puedes sacar el valor de un proceso asíncrono fuera de su entorno (en este caso fuera de `then`). Debes modificar la vista una vez que obtienes los datos, es decir, dentro de `then`.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Hacer que una promesa regrese algo para seguir trabajando en código síncrono](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/364535/hacer-que-una-promesa-regrese-algo-para-seguir-trabajando-en-c%c3%b3digo-s%c3%adncrono)

Comment: Entiendo lo que quieres decir @MauricioContreras, entiendo que una vez en asíncrono no puedes volver a síncrono, pero sigo sin entender como hacer el await en mi caso para poder resolver tal respuesta asíncrona

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para renderizar las cartas, se tiene que usar async y await en cada petición para tratar las peticiones asíncronas, para renderizar las cartas con react se debe tener en cuenta los lifecycles. Una vez se tienen los datos la función render ya hace automáticamente el renderizado de estos y se retorna la estructura HTML.

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

// Estructura de los datos en React
export default class FetchEquipo extends React.Component {
    state = {
        loading: true,
        equipo: null,
        jugadores: null,
        edadMedia: null,
        valorTotal: null,
        valorMedio: null
    };

    // Inicio de la petición asincrona a la API
    async componentDidMount() {
        const url = "http://localhost:8000/api/Equipos/?format=json";
        // Await de la función para esperar a la respuesta asincrona y obtener los datos
        const response = await axios.get(url);
        const data = await response.data;
        // Cambio del estado de los datos porque llegado aquí ya se han recibido
        for (let index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
            this.setState({ equipo: data[index], loading: false });
        }

    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.loading == true) {
            return (
                <div>
                    <p>Loading...</p>
                </div>
            );
        }
        else if (this.state.equipo == null) {
            return (
                <div>
                    <p>No se encontraron datos de los equipos</p>
                </div>
            );
        }
        else{
            return (
                <div>

                    <h1>{this.state.equipo.Equipo}</h1>
                    <h2>Jugadores: {this.state.equipo.Jugadores}</h2>
                    <h2>Edad media: {this.state.equipo.EdadMedia}</h2>
                    <h2>Valor total: {this.state.equipo.ValorTotal}</h2>
                    <h2>Valor Medio: {this.state.equipo.ValorMedio}</h2>

                </div>
            );
        }
    }
}
```