# Promesa dentro de un ciclo map

Tags: javascript, bucles, promesas

Buen día, estoy imprimiendo datos dentro de un arreglo pero necesito validar unos datos con una función que hace una consulta a una API, pero al finalizar me regresa un [object Promise]

```
app.get('/',  (request, response)=>{

    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=CFDINovalan.txt");
    response.setHeader("Content-type", "text/plain");
    response.charset = "ANSI";
    cfdiJson.map((cfdi, index) => {
      valor = estatus(cfdi.emisor.rfc, cfdi.receptor.rfc, cfdi.total, cfdi.timbreFiscal.uuid)
      response.write(`${cfdi.timbreFiscal.uuid} | ${cfdi.emisor.rfc} | ${cfdi.receptor.rfc} | ${cfdi.total} | ${valor} \n`);
    })
    response.end();
})
```

La función es:

```
async function estatus (Emisor, Receptor, Total, Uuid) {
  await axios.get(`https://api/${Emisor}&&${Receptor}&&${Total}&&${Uuid}`)
    .then(response => {
     return(response.data.estado)

    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```

y mi resultado:

```
XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX | XXXXXXXX | XXXXXX | 999.99 | [object Promise]
```

imprime Objet Promise y no el valor de la función.

¿Estoy haciendo algo mal?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Hacer que una promesa regrese algo para seguir trabajando en código síncrono](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/364535/hacer-que-una-promesa-regrese-algo-para-seguir-trabajando-en-c%c3%b3digo-s%c3%adncrono)

Comment: Intenta enviar lo que hay que hacer con los datos por callback a la función que realiza la consulta, de esa manera se ejecutara únicamente cuando el dato ya este resuelto.