# Como asignar el valor de una promesa a una variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, async-await

Tengo esto:

```
var archivo = subirArchivo().then(function(data){               
    return data;
});

function subirArchivo()
{
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var archivo = $("#uploadArchivo")[0];
  
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("archivo", archivo.files[0]);
    
    $.ajax({
       url: "includes/upload_archivo.php",  
       type: "POST",
       data: formData,
       cache: false,
       contentType: false,
       processData: false,
       xhr: function(){
            xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            $(".img-carga").css("visibility", "visible");

            xhr.upload.onprogress = function(ev){
                if(ev.lengthComputable)
                {
                    var percentComplete = parseInt((ev.loaded / ev.total) * 100);
                    
                    if(percentComplete == 100)
                    {
                        $(".img-carga").css("visibility", "hidden");    
                    }
                }
            }
            
            return xhr;
       },
       success: function(data){
           var arrFile = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
           
           if(arrFile.estado == 1)
               resolve(arrFile.archivo);
           else
               resolve("");
       }
    });
  });
}
```

Lo que deseo es asignar a una variable el valor que devuelve la promesa, como puedo hacer eso??

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Hacer que una promesa regrese algo para seguir trabajando en código síncrono](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/364535/hacer-que-una-promesa-regrese-algo-para-seguir-trabajando-en-c%c3%b3digo-s%c3%adncrono)

Answer (score 2):

Utiliza `async` y `await`:

```
(async() => {
    
    const archivo = await subirArchivo();
    
    /*.. resto del código ..*/
    
})();
```

- [async function - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)
- [await - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

Answer (score 0):

Todo se esta almacenando en tu variable `archivo`

```javascript
var archivo = subirArchivo().then(function(data){               
    return data;
});
```

Pues estas creando una función que retorna la promesa.

si te fijas al crear la promesa tienes 2 parametros `resolve, reject`.

en tu variable archivo le estas diciendo `resolve` con el `then` y `reject` con un catch que por buena practica debes manejarlo tambien.

Por lo tanto tendrías los siguiente.

```javascript
var archivo = subirArchivo().then(function(data){               
    return data;
}).catch(error => console.error(error));
```

o si quieres manejarlo por variables separadas

```javascript
const okResult;
const errorResult;
subirArchivo().then(function(data){               
    okResult = data;
}).catch(error => 
    errorResult = error;
);
```

aca un poco mas de [promesas](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)