# Obtener datos de una promesa

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

como andan?
Soy nuevo en desarrollo, estoy aprendiendo react.

No estoy pudiendo acceder al valor que me arroja una función.

Función:

```
introducir el const ordersId = async () => {
    const orders = []
    const q = query(collection(db, "orders"), orderBy("date", "desc"))

    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q)

    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        orders.push(doc.id)
    })

    return orders
}
```

cuando consoleo el resultado me arroja una promesa! ya probe varias formas y no le encuentro la vuelta

Muchas gracias

Comment: Relacionado: [Hacer que una promesa regrese algo para seguir trabajando en código síncrono](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/364535/hacer-que-una-promesa-regrese-algo-para-seguir-trabajando-en-c%c3%b3digo-s%c3%adncrono/364745#364745)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las funciones asincrónicas SIEMPRE devuelven una promesa, por tanto, para poder acceder a los datos que retorna, debes hacerlo a través del método `.then` y utilizando un callback. No puedes acceder a la variable que retorna como si fuera código sincrónico.

Cuando una promesa se resuelve, su resultado se pasa como argumento a un callback, y es ahí donde puedes utilizar lo que retorna la función. No puedes utilizarlo fuera de ese callback, porque estamos hablando de código asincrónico, no hay manera de asegurar cuando van a estar listos tus datos. Cuando lo estén, se llamará al callback.

Por ejemplo, en tu caso, para acceder al resultado de la función `ordersId` e imprimirlo en pantalla podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
ordersId().then(orders => console.log(orders))
```

La función se llamará, y cuando se resuelva la promesa, tus resultados serán pasados a la función `console.log()` para ser impresos en pantalla. Si quieres programar la lógica que maneje los datos que devuelve la promesa a través de una función, podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
function callback(orders) {
   //Lo que sea que quieras hacer con la variable orders
    console.log(orders);
}

ordersId().then(callback)
```

Con el uso de promesas, también puedes manejar los errores que puedan ocurrir a través del método catch. Cualquier error que ocurra, será capturado y pasado al callback de catch para el manejo de errores.

```
    function callback(orders) {
       //Lo que sea que quieras hacer con la variable orders
        console.log(orders);
    }

    function manejoDeErrores(error) {
       //Lo que harás si hay errores
        console.log(error);
    }
    
    ordersId().then(callback).catch(manejoDeErrores)
```

Puedes encontrar más información en la [documentación de MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Comment: excelente, muchas gracias!