# evitar anidar codigo dentro de un fetch then eh utilizar datos en una capa anterior

Tags: javascript, refactoring

si tengo un método asíncrono lo puedo meter dentro de un promesa para obligarlo a esperar que se cumpla pero utilizarlo en una instancia anterior:

Este es el ejemplo:

```js
class meta {
    obj = null;
    test = () => {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            fetch('https://reqres.in/api/products/3')
                .then((response) => {
                    this.obj = response;
                    resolve(true);
                });
        })
    }
}

let mt = new meta();

mt.test().then(()=>{
    console.log(mt.obj); // en este punto siempre tendra un valor la variable y puede ser usada en esta instancia.
})
```

Esto es correcto o existe una mejor forma de hacerlo? con esto evito el tener que continuar anidando codigo dentro del fetch then ....

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Hacer que una promesa regrese algo para seguir trabajando en código síncrono](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/364535/hacer-que-una-promesa-regrese-algo-para-seguir-trabajando-en-c%c3%b3digo-s%c3%adncrono)

Comment: @MauricioContreras lo que sugieres como respuesta ***duplicada*** no usa clases; ni objetos. puedes dar una solución mas especifica, al escenario presentado?

Comment: Da igual si usas clases u objetos, **no puedes** sacar el valor de una Promesa o de un código asíncrono fuera de su entorno, sea callback o `then`. ;)

Comment: De todas formas, en la respuesta que enlazo doy un pequeño truco sobre cómo hacerlo: *ejecuta todo tu código dentro de un entorno `async` y utiliza `await` para cada petición asíncrona*. Saludos

Comment: no puedo tomar tu comentario como respuesta; no es el mismo escenario, ni se como aplicarlo al entorno de una clase. sigo buscando lo que aporta tu respuesta en la otra pregunta a mi pregunta pero no logro entender el truco que debo adivinar...

Comment: @MauricioContreras te deje un comentario en tu respuesta y del por que mi pregunta no es igual a lo que planteas ...

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131227/discussion-between-mauricio-contreras-and-arcanis-the-omnipotent).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal como explico en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/364535/hacer-que-una-promesa-regrese-algo-para-seguir-trabajando-en-c%c3%b3digo-s%c3%adncrono), no puedes "sacar" a *una instancia anterior* el resultado de una Promesa. Pero más allá de este hecho, el error cometido por el OP en esta pregunta es bastante difícil de comprender cuando se está aprendiendo el lenguaje y su forma de trabajar, por lo cual cabe la respuesta.

**PROBLEMA**

Se tiene una [Clase](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) (que no es más que [*azúcar sintáctico*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Az%C3%BAcar_sint%C3%A1ctico) del sistema de herencia de prototipos de Javascript) con métodos [asíncronos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Asynchronous), en este caso llamadas a la [API Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).

La idea del OP es utilizar el resultado de estas llamadas como respuesta de los métodos de las instancias de dicha Clase, entiéndase *objetos*.

Sin embargo, debido a la naturaleza asíncrona de las llamadas a la API Fetch, los resultados de estos métodos no están disponibles de forma síncrona (inmediata a la llamada) sino que estarán disponibles en un futuro incierto. Por lo cual, no es posible la asignación de dichos resultados a una variable, sino que se debe usar métodos [`then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) ya que la API Fetch devuelve Promesas.

El OP se plantea si esto es correcto:

```js
mt.test().then(()=>{
    console.log(mt.obj);
});
```

Pero el resultado de esta llamada es el siguiente:

```js
{
  "type": "cors",
  "url": "https://reqres.in/api/products/3",
  "redirected": false,
  "status": 200,
  "ok": true,
  "statusText": "",
  "headers": {
    "append": function append() { [native code] },
    "delete": function delete() { [native code] },
    "get": function get() { [native code] },
    "has": function has() { [native code] },
    "set": function set() { [native code] },
    "entries": function entries() { [native code] },
    "forEach": function forEach() { [native code] },
    "keys": function keys() { [native code] },
    "values": function values() { [native code] }
  },
  "body": {
    "locked": false,
    "cancel": function cancel() { [native code] },
    "getReader": function getReader() { [native code] },
    "pipeThrough": function pipeThrough() { [native code] },
    "pipeTo": function pipeTo() { [native code] },
    "tee": function tee() { [native code] }
  },
  "bodyUsed": false,
  "arrayBuffer": function arrayBuffer() { [native code] },
  "blob": function blob() { [native code] },
  "clone": function clone() { [native code] },
  "formData": function formData() { [native code] },
  "json": function json() { [native code] },
  "text": function text() { [native code] }
}
```

Viendo el método `test` de la Clase:

```js
test = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    fetch('https://reqres.in/api/products/3')
    .then((response) => {
      this.obj = response;
      resolve(true);
    });
  })
}
```

Se observa que efectivamente hay una asignación de un valor a la propiedad `obj`, pero el valor de dicha asignación es el resultado de la llamada a `fetch` que es un objeto llamado [`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Response).

Otro problema con esta implementación es el uso innecesario de una Promesa, porque `fetch` devuelve ya una Promesa, y no necesito envolverla en otra para que funcione.

Por lo cual, la propiedad `obj` de `mt`, al ejecutar el método `then` en la llamada a `mt.test()`, contiene el objeto `Response`.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Tal vez el OP no se ha documentado completamente en el uso de la API Fecth, en todo caso, el resultado inmediato de una llamada a dicha API es un objeto, como ya he mencionado que contiene la totalidad de la respuesta recibida, incluyendo cabeceras, cuerpo y demás.

Este objeto dispone de varios métodos, entre los cuales destacan [`text()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/text) y [`json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json). El primero analiza (*parse*) el cuerpo de la solicitud y devuelve una Promesa que contiene el cuerpo en formato texto (`String`). El segundo método hace lo mismo pero espera que el cuerpo de la solicitud tenga formato `json` y devuelve un Objeto de Javascript construido a partir de la cadena `json` del cuerpo.

Suponiendo que no sabemos de antemano el tipo de resultado devuelto por el servidor al que hacemos la llamada, podemos usar el método `get` del objeto `headers` incluido en el objeto `Response` que nos permite inspeccionar las cabeceras y en particular obtener la cabecera `Content-Type`. Por ejemplo:

```js
fetch('https://reqres.in/api/products/3')
.then(response => {
  let contentType = response.headers.get('Content-Type');
  console.log(contentType);
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

A la vista del resultado obtenido, podemos usar el método `json` para analizar el cuerpo de la solicitud y obtener el mismo como un objeto de Javascript:

```js
fetch('https://reqres.in/api/products/3')
.then(response => {
  return response.json();
})
.then(json => {
  console.log(json);
})
```

Lo que desea el OP es asignar el resultado de la llamada (el cuerpo) ya analizado (*parsed*) a la propiedad `obj` de nuestra instancia de la Clase `Meta`. (Usar nombres de Clase en mayúscula es una buena práctica). Por lo cual podemos escribir lo siguiente:

```js
fetch('https://reqres.in/api/products/3')
.then(response => {
  return response.json();
})
.then(json => {
  this.obj = json
});
```

Con esto hemos completado la llamada al método `fetch` y podemos usarlo en nuestra Clase de la siguiente forma:

```js
class Meta {
  obj = null;
  test = () => {
    return fetch('https://reqres.in/api/products/3')
    .then(response => response.json())  // <- ejecuto la función que devuelve una Promesa
    .then(data => {
      this.obj = data;  // asigno el objeto a la propiedad obj de la Clase
    })
    .catch(console.log)  // un poquito de programación funcional :)            
  }
}

let mt = new Meta();

mt.test().then(() =>{
  console.log(mt.obj); // <- ahora si obj contiene lo que me interesa
});
```

Ahora el código se ejecuta correctamente.

En todo caso, para la duda planteada por el OP: *Esto es correcto o existe una mejor forma de hacerlo?*, habiendo realizado la corrección del código, la respuesta es: Si, es correcto realizarlo de dicha forma, es decir, acceder a la propiedad de la instancia una vez que se han ejecutado los procesos asíncronos inherentes. Sin embargo no puedo decirte que *exista* una mejor forma de hacerlo porque ello dependerá de lo que necesites en tu implementación.

Una forma *diferente* de hacerlo, que implica simplemente una mejora *visual* del código es usando entornos tipo `async`.

Por ejemplo, si envuelves toda tu lógica en una función `async` auto llamada, podrías hacer uso de `await` evitando así el uso de `then`. Toma en cuenta que el método `test()` de tu Clase debes declararlo de tipo `async` para poder usar `await` con la API Fetch.

Por ejemplo:

```js
// función async autollamada (nótese los paréntesis en la última línea)
(async function() {
  // usar nombres en mayúscula para las Clases es un plus
  class Meta {
    obj = null;
    test = async () => {
      // siempre que se trabaja con Promesas y
      // async / await, debemos usar bloques
      // try catch
      try {
        let res = await fetch('https://reqres.in/api/products/3');
        let json = await res.json();
        this.obj = json;            
      }
      catch(e) {
        console.error(e.message);
      }
    }
  }
  
  let mt = new Meta();
  await mt.test();
  console.log(mt.obj); // <- ahora sí, obj contiene lo que me interesa
})()
```

**Extra**

Las Clases (introducidas en ES6) son azúcar sintáctico de las funciones clásicas en Javascript y su sistema de herencia de prototipos.

Por lo cual decir que se trabaja [POO](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n_orientada_a_objetos) en Javascript, no es al final estrictamente cierto.

La introducción de las Clases, tal vez parte del hecho de hacer el lenguaje un poco más amigable con aquellos programadores acostumbrados a la POO.

No existe un tipo `Class` en Javascript, tal como en otros lenguajes, por lo cual, al final una Clase es simplemente una forma sintáctica diferente de escribir una función.

Veamos:

```js
// función típica de JS

function soy_una_funcion(mensaje) {
  this.msg = mensaje;
  this.showMessage = function() {
    console.log(this.msg);
  }
  return this;
}

const f = soy_una_funcion("Hola función");
f.showMessage();

console.log(typeof soy_una_funcion);
console.log(typeof f);  // <- objeto con herencia de prototipos

// Clase de ES6
class Soy_Una_Clase {
  constructor(mensaje) {
    this.msg = mensaje;
  }
  showMessage() {
    console.log(this.msg);
  }
}

const o = new Soy_Una_Clase("Hola Clase");
o.showMessage();

console.log(typeof Soy_Una_Clase);
console.log(typeof o);  // <- objeto con herencia de prototipos
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Como puedes observar, la Clase no es más que una forma diferente de declarar una función en Javascript.

Una lectura recomendada sería: [Prototipos de Objetos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes) en Javascript.

Comment: ahora si tiene sentido ... si vez el codigo de la extension de chrome que estoy haciendo te va a dar un infarto XD, voy a tener que refactorizar el 80% del codigo al final XD ... hace lo que debe hacer pero el código esta mal estructurado o escrito ... jamas pensé decir eso XD

Comment: para que vayas teniendo una idea solo hechale un vistaso a este link: https://github.com/IcarosNetSA/atsu/blob/main/src/js/document.js

Answer (score 1):

Si no me equivoco, se podría simplificar algo más de la siguiente manera (además de añadirle un catch por si hay erorres):

```js
class meta {
    obj = null;
    test = () => {
         return fetch('https://reqres.in/api/products/3')
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => this.obj = data)
                .catch(e => console.log(e))
                
    }
}

let mt = new meta();

mt.test().then(()=>{
    console.log(mt.obj); // en este punto siempre tendra un valor la variable y puede ser usada en esta instancia.
})
```

Comment: da error tu respuesta...

Comment: comprueba ahora, era un error de paréntesis

Comment: Hola, pues cuando lo ejecuto sale `function json() {[native code]}` puedes comparar las ejecuciones.

Comment: Tu respuesta tiene un error. Cuando haces: `.then(response => response.json)` estás devolviendo la función `json` y no la Promesa de su ejecución. Lo correcto sería: `.then(response => response.json())` (nótese la llamada a `json` con los paréntesis finales). Saludos

Comment: Cierto Mauricio, típicos errores al escribir el código sin editor. Aplico el cambio.