# Como obtener la respuesta de una promesa fuera de una función en javasscript

Tags: javascript, nodejs, async-await

Tengo una caonsulta a una base de datos en un archivo y quiero obtener sus datos al comienzo de un archivo de funciones

```
    const getData = async () => {
    try {
        client = await MongoClient.connect(URI);
        const db = await client.db(mongoDB);
        const mongoObject = await db.collection(colectionName).find({}).project({ _id: 0}).toArray();
        const mongoData = await mongoObject.map(item => item.itemId)
        return mognoBlocked_SKUS

    } catch (err) {
        console.log('err', err)
    }
}

module.exports = {
    getData
}
```

Quiero obtener la informacion en otro archivo al comienzo para manejar la data.

```
const {getData} = require('./getData')


const getData= getData()

if (getData.includes(value)) {
            return result;
        }
```

Sin embargo no se como obtener la informacion fuera de otras fucniones, y que este disponible para todas mis funciones siguientes.

Comment: mal, no debeias volver a conectarte cada vez que hagas una consulta, en un archivo deverias tener toda la configuracion de mongodb y a continuacion llamar a ese archivo al inicio de tu servidor, estoy te va ayudar a conectarte a la base de datos una vez iniciado el servidor, luego debes crear tus propios esquemas y a travez de esos esquemas deberias consultart a la db

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Hacer que una promesa regrese algo para seguir trabajando en código síncrono](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/364535/hacer-que-una-promesa-regrese-algo-para-seguir-trabajando-en-c%c3%b3digo-s%c3%adncrono)