# Mi método devuelve undefined en vez de booleano

Tags: javascript

tengo una función que verifica si el usuario es administrador o no, devolviéndome así 'true' o 'false', pero al hacer un console.log() me retorna un 'undefined'. ¿A qué es debido? Gracias.

```
function admin(ctx){
bot.telegram.getChatAdministrators(ctx.chat.id).then( (res) => {
    i = 0; isAdmin = false;
    while(i < res.length && !isAdmin){
        if(ctx.message.from.id == res[i].user.id){isAdmin = true;}
        i++;
    }
    return isAdmin;
})
}
```

Comment: `getChatAdministrators` es asíncrona, el resultado de la misma estará sólo dentro del método callback que estás usando en `then`. El llamado a `return` dentro de ese método no se propaga a tu función `admin`, es por ello que te devuelve `undefined`

Comment: Gracias, ¿entonces como podría hacer para que el valor retornado del método se propague a la función?

Comment: La respuesta corta: *no puedes*. La respuesta larga: [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/364535/hacer-que-una-promesa-regrese-algo-para-seguir-trabajando-en-c%c3%b3digo-s%c3%adncrono). Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aportación.

Answer (score -1):

Tienes mal el parámetro de paréntesis después del then

Prueba así que era del paréntesis mal escrito
También te he cambiado la negación de la variable IsAdmin

```
function admin(ctx){
bot.telegram.getChatAdministrators(ctx.chat.id).then(res => {
var i = 0; 
var isAdmin = false;
while(i < res.length && isAdmin == true){
    if(ctx.message.from.id == res[i].user.id){isAdmin = true;}
    i++;
}
return isAdmin;
  })
}
```

Comment: Tu respuesta está mal. Parece que ni siquiera lo probaste, eso te marcaría un error de sintaxis. 
`.then( (res) => {} )` y `.then( res => {} )` es lo mismo

Comment: No me había dado cuenta de un par de cosas que ahora si que están mejor...