# Como se resuelve esto con Promesas?

Tags: javascript, fetch, promesas, async-await

Este codigo funciona:

```
async function pokemons(){
   let pokemons = []
   let res = await fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon")
   let json = await res.json()
   
   for (let i = 0; i < json.results.length; i++) {
    let res = await fetch(json.results[i].url)
    pokemon = await res.json()
    
    pokemons.push(pokemon)
   }
   console.log(pokemons);

   let Final = pokemons.map(el => 
    [el.name, el.sprites.front_default])
    console.log(Final);
   }
  pokemons()
```

Como deberia hacer para obtener el resultado sin usar el settimeout, no logro darme cuenta donde poner asyn/await, o porque el ultimo then no espera al resultado de los anidados...

```
let pokemons = []
  fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon")

   .then(res => res.json())

   .then(json => {
    json.results.forEach(el => {
     fetch(el.url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
       let pokemon = {
        nombre: json.name,
        imagen: json.sprites.front_default
       };
       pokemons = [...pokemons, pokemon]
      })
    })
   })

   .then(pokemons => console.log(pokemons))

   setTimeout(() => {
   console.log(pokemons);
  }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu primer código funciona, pero no es óptimo. El el `fetch` con el `await` dentro del ciclo `for` se puede mejorar mucho con el [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

El problema con el `fetch` y el `await` dentro del ciclo `for` es que, cada petición tendrá que esperar a que la anterior se complete para comenzar una nueva. Pides un pokemon, cuando lo recibes, pides otro, cuando lo recibes, pides otro y así sucesivamente. Tienes siempre que estar **esperando que la anterior se complete** para iniciar la nueva petición.

Con `Promise.all` inicias **TODAS** las peticiones de un golpe, y las vas atendiendo a medidas de que cada una se vaya resolviendo. Fíjate que en este caso si la séptima petición se resuelve antes de que la primera, ganas un montón de tiempo, porque no tienes que esperar a que una se complete para que iniciar la otra. Las inicias todas "al mismo tiempo".

Puedes utilizar `Promise.all` tanto si estás usando la sintaxis clásica como la más moderna, o incluso con una combinación de las dos.

Si lo vas a hacer utilizando la sintaxis básica de promesas no necesitas el `async` y el `await`:

```js
fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => Promise.all(json.results.map(el => fetch(el.url))))
    .then(res => Promise.all(res.map(el => el.json())))
    .then(res => {
        let pokemons = res.map(json => {
            return {
                name: json.name,
                url: json.sprites.front_default
            }
        })
        console.log(pokemons)
    })
```

Alternativamente usando `async` y `await`:

```js
const getPokemons = async () => {
    const res = await fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon")
    const json = await res.json()
    const pokemonsRequest = json.results.map(el => fetch(el.url))
    const pokemonsResponse = await Promise.all(pokemonsRequest)
    const pokemonsList = await Promise.all(pokemonsResponse.map(el => el.json()))
    const pokemons = pokemonsList.map(json => {
        return {
            name: json.name,
            url: json.sprites.front_default
        }
    })
    console.log(pokemons)
}
getPokemons()
```

Comment: el tema es que no resuelve mi necesidad de asignar el resultado final a una variable global, ya que fuera del then sigo obteniendo un array vacio. De todos modos no conocia el Promise.all(), aunque mi codigo y tu codigo basado en promesas hacen lo mismo, llenan el array con los datos, el tema es que ninguno de los 2 se puede usar con variables globales

Comment: Tú puedes dentro del then asignar el valor a una variable global. Si lo que quieres es que una función asincrónica o una promesa te devuelva algo que no sea una promesa, me temo que no es posible.

Comment: [Lectura Recomendada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/364745/186586).

Comment: @HernánGarcia una función asíncrona SIEMPRE devuelve una promesa. Lo que sugeriste en la edición no es válido. Pruébalo tu mismo para que veas lo que te imprime. Obtendrás en la consola una Promise. Tienes que aprender a pensar de manera asíncrona. Haz una función donde pongas todo lo que quieres hacer cuando los datos estén listos, y llámala dentro del .then. Esa es la manera correcta de consumilo.

Comment: entiendo lo que dices, solo que necesitaba que ese array que se arma estuviera disponible globalmente (lo esta cuando se cumple la promesa). Suponte que con esos datos armo una grilla de cards con foto y nombre dell pokemon, y que al dar click sobre una de esas cards se me abre una nueva con la info ampliada de ese pokemon (no me interesan los pokemons, jaja, solo los uso de ejem). Entonces podria usar esa info global que traje anteriormente para armar la nueva card ampliada y no tener que peticionar nuevamente. sigo abajo...

Comment: ...Claro que entre que haces click y demas ya la peticion se completo y estaria la info disponible. O loo suyo seria hacer una nueva peticion para ese determinado pokemon y prescindir de variables globales?

Comment: Hernan, la petición puede demorar 0.5 segundos, o puede demorar 2 segundos o puede demorar 20 segundos. Tu no aplicación no debe depender del tiempo que se resuelva algo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu tiempo!!