# return en una funcion asíncrona (async/await)

Tags: javascript, function, promesas, async-await, async

Estoy aprendiendo Javascript y tengo una duda con las funciones asíncronas y cómo funciona el (async/await).
Hago una petición a la api de movieDB, luego a la respuesta la paso a json, pero el problema es cuando quiero utilizar fuera de la función el valor que me devuelva esta misma. Siempre me retorna una promesa sin resolver. He visto varios post similares pero aún no he logrado que funcione.

Esta función toma como parametro la página que quiero que se ejecute y me retorna una lista de 20 peliculas

```js
async function getMovieList(pag){
  const movie_list=[]
  const movies_text=await fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/top_rated?api_key=${api_key}&language=es-ES&page=${pag}`)
  const movies_json=await movies_text.json()
  return await movies_json
}

console.log(getMovieList(10))
```

Esta es muy similar pero toma como parámetro el id de una película y luego me devuelve información de ella.

```js
async function getMovie(movie_id){
  const movie_text=await fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${movie_id}?api_key=${api_key}&language=es-ES`)
  const movie_json=await movie_text.json()
  return movie_json
}
```

De la primera quiero sacar un array con los id de las pelicula que me devolvió, para luegos pasar esos id por la segunda función y así obtener mas información de c/película.

Comment: Una función asíncrona siempre retorna una promesa. Respuesta corta **NO SE PUEDE** retornar algo que no sea una promesa en una función asíncrona. [Respuesta larga acá](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/364745/186586). Solución: simplemente llama una función dentro de la otra. Otra solución  `getMovieList(pag).then(movies => {// acá puedes consumir el la lista de peliculas})`

Comment: Gracias Jaime. Estaba sospechando que no se podía jajaja. Intentaré utilizar los datos que me da getMovieList con getMovie, desde otra función que abarque a ambas. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

En mi caso, pude lograr algo similar utilizando `then`. No estoy seguro si es la práctica aceptada, pero espero te sirva.

Ejemplo:

```
let resp = getMovie(12).then(movie_text => console.log(movie_text));
```