# como retornar el resultado de una función asincrónica?

Tags: javascript, json

Intento leer y retornar un objeto traído de un JSON, usando File system para leer el objeto y retornar su valor fuera de la función pero al tratar de retornar el objeto leído correctamente con file system la promesa queda pendiente que puedo hacer?

```
let fs = require('fs');

let arch = async ()=>{
    try{
        let leer = await fs.promises.readFile('./archivo.json','utf-8');
        let le = JSON.parse(leer);
        return le;
    }catch(err){
        console.error(err)
    }
}
let ob = arch();
console.log(ob);
```

Comment: Te invito a leer mi respuesta sobre promises y el porque eso que quieres hacer no se puede, tienes que cambiar tu logica o la forma en como operas con el codigo asincrono, no esta mal, de no ser por la parte final. https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/364600/98940

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que está pasando es que el console.log se está ejecutando antes de que se resuelva la función arch entonces la Promesa no llega a resolverse antes del console.log.

Para resolver esto podrías usar el método [fs.readFileSync](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-fs-readfilesync-method/) que es sincrónico y así no tenés que manejar una promesa:

```
let ob = fs.readFileSync('./archivo.json','utf-8');
console.log(ob);
```

La otra opción sería agregar un await cuando ejecutas arch, para que se espere a la resolución de la promesa. Sin embargo, en este caso hay que tener en cuenta que await solo puede utilizarse dentro de una función async, y no es posible en un contexto global. Si el código está siendo ejecutado en un contexto global una posible solución sería usar una [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/IIFE):

```
let ob;
(async ()=>{
try{
    let leer = await    fs.promises.readFile('./archivo.json','utf-8');
                
    let ob = JSON.parse(leer);
  
}catch(err){
    console.error(err)
})();
console.log(ob);
```

Comment: Correcto por una parte, incorrecto por otra, correcto por lo primero (`readFileSync` funcionaria), el problema viene siendo mas abajo, `await arch()`, no funcionaria, siendo que en un contexto global no puedes usar `await`, por lo que, a manera de complemento y para que el usuario lo tenga en cuenta, si usas la ultima linea debes de encerrar todo tu codigo dentro de una funcion asincrona para que esta linea sea valida.

Comment: Si, es verdad que en un contexto global no funcionaria, ahi lo agrego. gracias