# Obtener resultado de funtion Async anidada en Promise All Js

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Tengo una función que me básicamente consulta todos los exchanges y las monedas que tengo alojadas en unas constantes. La información la consulta sin problemas sin embargo soy nuevo en esto de Node y tengo problemas con las promesas. Necesito retornar la consulta total con todos los resultados y mostrarlos todos juntos y la verdad no logro hacerlo bien, he intentado de muchísimas formas.

```
"use strict";

const ccxt = require("ccxt");
let dataCoins = [];
const exchanges = [
  ["binance", "USDT", ["BTC", "BNB"]],
  ["coinbase", "USD", ["BTC"]],
  ["kraken", "USDT", ["BTC"]],
  ["kucoin", "USDT", ["BTC", "BNB"]],
  ["bitstamp", "USDT", ["BTC"]],
  ["okx", "USDT", ["BTC"]],
  ["bybit", "USD:USDC", ["BTC", "BNB"]],
  ["bitget", "USDT", ["BTC", "BNB"]],
  ["gateio", "USDT", ["BTC", "BNB"]],
  ["cryptocom", "USDT", ["BTC"]],
  ["huobi", "USDT", ["BTC", "BNB"]],
];

const cryptoCoins = [ "BTC", "ETH", "BNB", "XRP", "DOGE", "ADA", "MATIC", "DOT", "DAI", "LTC", "SHIB", "TRX", "SOL", "UNI", "AVAX", "LINK", "XMR"];
let num = 0;

const consult = async () => {
  exchanges.forEach( (exch) => {
      const exchangeId = exch[0],
        exchangeClass = ccxt[exchangeId],
        exchange = new exchangeClass();
      let resp;

        cryptoCoins.forEach( async (coin) => {
          try {
            resp = await exchange.fetchTicker(`${coin}/${exch[1]}`);
            dataCoins.push({
              position: num,
              name: exchangeId,
              symbold: resp.symbol,
              bid: resp.bid,
              ask: resp.ask,
            });
          } catch (e) {
            dataCoins.push({
              position: num,
              name: exchangeId,
              symbold: `${coin}/${exch[1]}`,
              bid: "not value",
              ask: "not value",
            });
          }

          num++;
        })
  });
  console.log(await dataCoins);
};

consult();
```

Ese es mi codigo, es bien simple, espero alguien pueda ayudarme lo que necesito, es poder mostrar dataCoins completo, despues de que ejecute todos las consultas.

Tambien intente mediante Promise.All sin embargo debido a la gran cantidad de consultas, decidi recorrer primero cada una de las opciones generando la funcion para cada una y asi ejecutarla de manera asincrona, sin embargo si la coloco como una funcion en el foreach, osea dejandolas sin comillas, entonces me ejecuta la funcion al mismo tiempo que me recorre todo y la verdad nisiquiera funciona bien. Y si la dejo con comillas me lo toma como string y tampoco funciona.

```
"use strict";

const ccxt = require("ccxt");

const exchanges = [
  ["binance", "USDT"],
  ["coinbase", "USD"],
  ["kraken", "USDT"],
  ["kucoin", "USDT"],
  ["bitstamp", "USDT"],
  ["okx", "USDT"],
  ["bybit", "USD:USDC"],
//   ["bitget", "USDT"],
  ["gateio", "USDT"],
  ["cryptocom", "USDT"],
  ["huobi", "USDT"],
];

const cryptoCoins = [ "BTC", "ETH", "BNB", "XRP", "DOGE", "ADA", "MATIC", "DOT", "DAI", "LTC", "SHIB", "TRX", "SOL", "UNI", "AVAX", "LINK", "XMR"];

let consultData = [];

exchanges.forEach(exchange => {
  cryptoCoins.forEach(coins => {
    consultData.push(`consult(${exchange[0]},${exchange[1]},${coins})`)
  });
});

function consult(exch,par,coin){
        const exchangeId = exch
        const exchangeClass = ccxt[exchangeId]
        const exchange = new exchangeClass();
        let resp;

        return new Promise((resolved,reject) => {
            resp = exchange.fetchTicker(`${coin}/${par}`);
            resolved({
                name: exchangeId,
                symbold: resp.symbol,
                bid: resp.bid,
                ask: resp.ask,
            })

            reject({
                position: num,
                name: exchangeId,
                symbold: `${coin}/${par}`,
                bid: "not value",
                ask: "not value",
            })
        });
  
  };

Promise.all(consultData).then((response) => {
    console.log(response)
})
```

Necesito poder obtener los resultados ejecutando las funciones asincronas, pero me ha costado bastante.

Comment: No podrás "obtener" el resultado de una Promesa hasta que la misma sea "resuelta", por lo cual, si pretendes obtener directamente el resultado asignando el valor de la llamada a tu [método `async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) a una variable, dicha variable será siempre una Promesa. Saludos

Comment: Relacionado: [Hacer que una Promesa regrese algo para seguir trabajando en código síncrono](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/364535/hacer-que-una-promesa-regrese-algo-para-seguir-trabajando-en-c%c3%b3digo-s%c3%adncrono/364745#364745)

Comment: Mauricio muchas gracias por tu amabilidad, como comente soy un poco nuevo en esto, te explico, la teoria basica me la conozco, entiendo que lo retorna hasta que sea resuelta y eso esta bien, el problema es que si lo notas, tengo un foreach dentro de otro, y todo dentro de un Async general, basicamente estan anidados unos dentro de otros, y he intentado aplicar el concepto de todas las maneras posibles, pero aun no lo logro, podrias ilustrarme un poco. Disculpa las molestias, de verdad necesito ayuda, vine aca despues de intentarlo de muchas maneras.

Comment: Más allá del problema de asincronía, me preocupa la cantidad de peticiones que estás realizando a la API que deseas consultar. Suponiendo que se te permita dicha cantidad de consultas en un tiempo relativamente corto, lo suyo es usar Promise.all. En cuanto pueda veré de publicar una respuesta si nadie más lo ha hecho para entonces.

Comment: Si las permite son 187 consultas, y las hace en 20 seg que realmente es un buen numero, puesto que otros lo hacen en mas de 1 minuto. Pero vere lo de Promise all ire investigando, sin embargo si puedes ayudarme de verdad te lo agradezco, y no sabes cuanto

Comment: @MauricioContreras intente mediante Promise All pero sigo teniendo algunos problemas debido a que no se bien como poder manejar los múltiples funciones asincronas que se forman. Porque básicamente sigo dependiendo de varias. Si puedes ayudarme con una respuesta, te lo agradecería muchísimo, en funciones mas pequeñas si lo manejo pero aqui todavia no le agarro la onda.

Comment: @MauricioContreras he editado mi pregunta añadiendo algunos intentos que hice, pero nada. Estoy dando 50 de recompensa que no se si es mucho o poco, porque poco utilizo la plataforma, pero si puedes ayudarme te lo agradezco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para resolver tu problema, puedes utilizar la función Promise.all() para ejecutar todas las promesas al mismo tiempo y esperar a que todas se completen antes de procesar los resultados.

Por ejemplo, tu código podría verse de la siguiente manera:

```
"use strict";

const ccxt = require("ccxt");

const exchanges = [
  ["binance", "USDT"],
  ["coinbase", "USD"],
  ["kraken", "USDT"],
  ["kucoin", "USDT"],
  ["bitstamp", "USDT"],
  ["okx", "USDT"],
  ["bybit", "USD:USDC"],
  // ["bitget", "USDT"],
  ["gateio", "USDT"],
  ["cryptocom", "USDT"],
  ["huobi", "USDT"],
];

const cryptoCoins = ["BTC", "ETH", "BNB", "XRP", "DOGE", "ADA", "MATIC", "DOT", "DAI", "LTC", "SHIB", "TRX", "SOL", "UNI", "AVAX", "LINK", "XMR"];
let num = 0;

const consult = async () => {
  // Creamos un array de promesas, una por cada exchange
  const promises = exchanges.map((exch) => {
    const exchangeId = exch[0],
      exchangeClass = ccxt[exchangeId],
      exchange = new exchangeClass();
    let resp;

    // Creamos un array de promesas, una por cada criptomoneda
    return Promise.all(
      cryptoCoins.map(async (coin) => {
        try {
          resp = await exchange.fetchTicker(`${coin}/${exch[1]}`);
          return {
            position: num,
            name: exchangeId,
            symbold: resp.symbol,
            bid: resp.bid,
            ask: resp.ask,
          };
        } catch (e) {
          return {
            position: num,
            name: exchangeId,
            symbold: `${coin}/${exch[1]}`,
            bid: "not value",
            ask: "not value",
          };
        }
      })
    );
  });

  // Esperamos a que todas las promesas se completen
  const dataCoins = await Promise.all(promises);

  // Procesamos los resultados
  console.log(dataCoins);
};

consult();
```

Con estos cambios, la función consult() retornará una promesa que se completará cuando todas las promesas dentro de la función se completen. Esto te permitirá procesar los resultados de manera adecuada y mostrarlos de manera correcta en la consola.

Comment: Muchas gracias no tienes idea cuanto me costo encontrar una solución, ahora obviamente lo entiendo, y ya puedo aplicarlo a otros problemas, le problema es entenderlo la primera vez jajajajajaja. En 17 horas podre liberarte la recompensa.