# Convertir un async function en una funcion normal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promesas, try-catch

quería saber si es posible convertir mi funcion trans a una funcion normal que retorne el valor en `string` sin necesidad de devolver una `Promise`

```
const useTraduce = () => {
  const trans = async (text) => {
    let newText = text;
    newText = await translate(text, { from: 'es', to: 'en' });
    return newText;
  };

  return trans;
};

export default useTraduce;
```

Me gustaria poder llamar a trans de la siguiente forma:

```
const translation = useTraduce()
return <div>{translation('hola mundo')}</div> // ✅ Hello world
```

Es posible hacer asi? ya que ahora `translation` me devuelve una promise pero me gustaria que no fuese asi por el tipo de producto que estoy resolviendo.

---

1. Cabe mensionar que se esta utilizando `google-cloud` para solicitar a la api de google translate que haga las traducciones que se piden.
2. No me funciona guardar el `nextText` en un estado de `react`, debera la propia funcion `trans` retorna el valor de la solicitud

Comment: No es posible. O que suele hacerse es mostrar algún componente que indique que se está cargando (spinner) la , sin renderizar el resultado parcial.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Hacer que una promesa regrese algo para seguir trabajando en código síncrono](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/364535/hacer-que-una-promesa-regrese-algo-para-seguir-trabajando-en-c%c3%b3digo-s%c3%adncrono)

Comment: Más allá del hecho que no puedes convertir código async en código síncrono, ¿Porqué usar un servicio externo para la traducción de la página? Supongamos que deseas hacerlo con el servicio externo, ¿Porqué no proveer un valor por defecto mientras la respuesta del servicio externo es recibida? Mi recomendación es que uses tu propio servicio de internacionalización con [`react-i18next`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-i18next)

Comment: @MauricioContreras es para contenido dinámico, entiendo lo que planteas de i18next pero en este escenario no aplica.